# How to reduce Nonclustered index scan cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that is running on MS Access and the NonClustered scan in the execution plan has a cost of 100% in our SSMS. This query has the second highes processing time, which means this reduces our applications speed when this is executed. I am wondering if anyone knows what i can do to reduce the cost% for this Nonclustered index? Below is the query that is calling this table, the indexed for this table and the execution plan.

```
SELECT "ContactID" ,"ContactName"  FROM "dbo"."Contacts"
```

Here the execution plan:

[image]

Here are the indexes that are in the table that this slow query is referencing:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query has no WHERE clause, so there's no way to avoid scanning the whole table, since you're asking for every row to be returned.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to make this process faster with any new indexes or anything? @Joe Stefanelli

Comment: @ETA: Put enough RAM into the SQL Server to cache the whole table and make sure the LAN speed between the SQL Server and the Access client application is as fast as possible. Or just query the rows that you *actually need* instead of the whole table.

Comment: @ETA Your query is already using the best index possible. That is, the one that covers your query by containing all of the columns in your SELECT clause. As mentioned in my answer, without a WHERE clause to reduce the number of rows returned, this is as good as it gets.

Comment: Using a covering index so that it does an index scan rather than a table scan is the best you are going to get with this particular query.  If this is an issue for applications then you might want to consider having your application do some kind of caching or some other design strategy that doesn't require you to pull every record from the table